# Make border around text in p in span in div

Tags: html, css

When I put the border around the div or p element its just too long .
If I put it in the span container it does not make a "quadratic container" around the text.
I want the border to be just around the text. I guess one does not need more information . A html output would be useless. Thanks for helping.

```css
    border-top:1px solid #000000;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
    border-left:1px solid #000000;
    border-right:1px solid #000000;
```

```html
<div class="tags"> <span class="icons2"> <p class="jobAreaDescription">{{jobArea}}</p> </span></div>
```

Comment: The css in the snippet is invalid.

Comment: You're not supposed to put a `<p>`, which is a block level element inside an inline element like `<span>`. `I guess one does not need more information` I guess one does though. What does `icons2` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify the element on which the style should work. Simply the `border` property should work with `display:inline-block`.
You can try the following way

```css
p.jobAreaDescription{
  border:1px solid #000000;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tags"> <span class="icons2"> <p class="jobAreaDescription">{{jobArea}}</p> </span></div>
```

Comment: Why the cheap, mindless drive-by points grabbing? Is this really what this website is for?

Comment: @ChrisG, no problem being cheap, mindless in helping others!!!

Comment: I'm not saying don't help others, I'm saying this answer ignores the invalid HTML in OP's code and encourages precisely the kind of questions that should never be posted here in the first place. If you don't care whether SO devolves into another yahoo answers, fine, but don't act all surprised if people *do* care.

Comment: @ChrisG, and the meaning of *care* seems vary from person to person!!!

Comment: What's your point? I was ready to help OP in the comments as you can see, but thanks to you shooting from the hip OP will now happily move on with their bad HTML. Why are you trying to paint me as somebody who shits on newbies when I clearly don't? This is about the general quality of this site. Feel morally superior all you like, but you are not addressing my criticism at all.

Answer (score 1):

I hope, this code helps you!!

You can use 'p' tag or class, it's your project or scenario depends. Both are working.

```css
p{
   border:1px solid #000;
   display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="tags"> <p class="jobAreaDescription">{{jobArea}}</p> </div>
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: This works however it will change all `<p>` tags in the document

Comment: @Nodejs-nerd You can check proper my answer,  I already told that use 'p' tag or class name, it works in both cases. It's just a sample to solve a problem.

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this would be with the following code

```css
.jobAreaDescription {
  border:1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div class="tags"> 
  <span class="icons2"> 
    <p class="jobAreaDescription">
       {{jobArea}}
    </p> 
  </span>
</div>
```

This is just css modifying the class `jobAreaDescription` so it doesnt matter that it is inside a `<div>` and `<span>`